# Using antd after initializing app with CRA

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, antd

Here is my case:
I initialized a project using `create-react-app` and I just figured out that using antd will be difficult.
I followed the steps in the dedicated part on ant design web site and it doesn't work. I tried to eject my project but when I do I have an error `'config' already exists in your app folder` (I don't know what is that config).
I can't make ant working. I tried to add a simple button with the ant style but in the browser the button is a basic html button.
My question is: is there a way to use antd after creating a react application using CRA ?
I've read a lot of stuff on internet but accordingly to these posts and commentaries, nothing seems to work. Should I create a new project ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Sorry, but did you try this: https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app ?
I've done it before, and it worked without any problem. How exactly is it not working?

Comment: @iagowp Hi, yes I tried that. I tried to import the antd.css but I have an error because the css file is not in the src folder (it is in node_module). I installed the react-app-rewired, I changed the "scripts" part in the package.json and I added the  config-overrides.js. I also imported babel-plugin-import. When I change the config-overrides.js to import antd with babel, I have the error "Module build failed: Reference error: Unknown plugin "import" sepcified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "path"".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution.
I followed the steps here  ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app and my mistake was installing babel-import-plugin globaly instead of directly in the project. So everything seems to work now.
Sorry for that and thanks @iagowp for the help.